# I want to find the length of my each words in text file

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to find the length of words individually in my text file. I tried it by following code but this code is showing me up the count of words that how many times this word is used in file.

```
text = open(r"C:\Users\israr\Desktop\counter\Bigdata.txt") 
d = dict() 

for line in text: 
    line = line.strip() 
    line = line.lower()
    words = line.split(" ") 

    for word in words: 
        if word in d: 
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else: 
            # Add the word to dictionary with count 1 
            d[word] = 1

for key in list(d.keys()): 
    print(key, ":", d[key])
```

And the output is something like this

```
china : 14
emerged : 1
as : 16
one : 5
of : 44
the : 108
world's : 7
first : 2
civilizations, : 1
in : 26
fertile : 1
basin : 1
yellow : 1
river : 1
north : 1
plain. : 1
```

Basically i want a list of words having same length for example china , first , world :5 this 5 is the length of all this words and so on the words having different length in other list

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you expected?

Comment: Did you try changing `d[key]` to `len(key)` when printing the results?

Comment: Basically i want a list of words having same length for example  china  , first  , world  :5  this 5 is the length of all this words  and so on the words having different length in other list

Comment: @IsrarAwan  edited the solution, but do you know what you want really?

Comment: @lapestand yes i edited my question sorry for this actually i'm new and that's my 2nd time  but next i'd ask clearly thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the code for dealing with each word, you will see your problem..

```
for word in words: 
        if word in d: 
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else: 
            # Add the word to dictionary with count 1 
            d[word] = 1
```

Here you are checking if a word is in the dictionary. If it is, add 1 to its key when we find it. If it is not, initialize it at 1. This is the core concept for counting repetitions.

If you want to count the length of the word, you could simply do.

```
for word in words: 
        if word not in d: 
            d[word] = len(word)
```

And to output your dict, you can do

```
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, ":", v)
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your help this is working but now actually i want  to store all words in a list having same length ....

Answer (score 1):

İf you need all word's total lengths seperatly, you can find them using this formula:

`len(word) * count(word)` for all `word` in `words`

equalivent in python:
`d[key] * len(key)`

Change last 2 lines with below:

```
for key in list(d.keys()):
    print(key, ":", d[key] * len(key))
```

----EDIT----
It ıs what you asked in comments, I guess. Below code gives you groups whose members are the same length.

```
    for word in words:
        if len(word) in d:
            if word not in d[len(word)]:
                d[len(word)].append(word)
        else:
            # Add the word to dictionary with count 1
            d[len(word)] = [word]

for key in list(d.keys()):
    print(key, ":", d[key])
```

Output of this code:

```
3 : ['the', 'bc,', '(c.', 'who', 'was', '100', 'bc)', 'and', 'xia', 'but', 'not', 'one', 'due', '8th', '221', 'qin', 'shi', 'for', 'his', 'han', '220', '206', 'has', 'war', 'all', 'far']
8 : ['earliest', 'describe', 'writings', 'indicate', 'commonly', 'however,', 'cultural', 'history,', 'regarded', 'external', 'internal', 'culture,', 'troubled', 'imperial', 'selected', 'replaced', 'republic', 'mainland', "people's", 'peoples,', 'multiple', 'kingdoms', 'xinjiang', 'present.', '(carried']
5 : ['known', 'china', 'early', 'shang', 'texts', 'grand', 'ruled', 'river', 'which', 'along', 'these', 'arose', 'years', 'their', 'rule.', 'began', 'first', 'those', 'huang', 'title', 'after', 'until', '1912,', 'tasks', 'elite', 'young', '1949.', 'unity', 'being', 'civil', 'parts', 'other', 'world', 'waves', 'basis']
7 : ['written', 'records', 'history', 'dynasty', 'ancient', 'century', 'mention', 'writing', 'period,', 'xia.[5]', 'valley,', 'chinese', 'various', 'centers', 'yangtze', "world's", 'cradles', 'concept', 'mandate', 'justify', 'central', 'country', 'smaller', 'period.', 'another', 'warring', 'created', 'himself', 'huangdi', 'marking', 'systems', 'enabled', 'emperor', 'control', 'routine', 'handled', 'special', 'through', "china's", 'between', 'periods', 'culture', 'western', 'foreign']
2 : ['of', 'as', 'wu', 'by', 'no', 'is', 'do', 'in', 'to', 'be', 'at', 'or', 'bc', '21', 'ad']
4 : ['date', 'from', '1250', 'bc),', 'king', 'such', 'book', '11th', '(296', 'held', 'both', 'with', 'zhou', 'into', 'much', 'qin,', 'fell', 'soon', '(206', 'ad).', 'that', 'vast', 'were', 'men,', 'last', 'qing', 'then', 'most', 'whom', 'eras', 'have', 'some', 'asia', 'form']
9 : ['1600–1046', 'mentioned', 'documents', 'chapters,', 'historian', '2070–1600', 'existence', 'neolithic', 'millennia', 'thousands', '(1046–256', 'pressures', 'following', 'developed', 'conquered', '"emperor"', 'beginning', 'dynasties', 'directly.', 'centuries', 'carefully', 'difficult', 'political', 'dominated', 'stretched', 'contact),']
6 : ['during', "ding's", '(early', 'bamboo', 'annals', 'before', 'shang,', 'yellow', 'cradle', 'river.', 'shang.', 'oldest', 'heaven', 'weaken', 'states', 'spring', 'autumn', 'became', 'warred', 'times.', 'china.', 'death,', 'peace,', 'failed', 'recent', 'steppe', 'china;', 'tibet,', 'modern']
12 : ['reign,[1][2]', 'twenty-first', 'longer-lived', 'bureaucratic', 'calligraphy,', '(1644–1912),', '(1927–1949).', 'occasionally', 'immigration,']
11 : ['same.[3][4]', 'independent', 'traditional', 'territories', 'well-versed', 'literature,', 'philosophy,', 'assimilated', 'population.', 'warlordism,']
10 : ['historical', 'originated', 'continuous', 'supplanted', 'introduced', 'government', 'eventually', 'splintered', 'literature', 'philosophy', 'oppressive', 'successive', 'alternated', 'influences', 'expansion,']
1 : ['a', '–']
13 : ['civilization.', 'civilizations', 'examinations.', 'statehood—the', 'assimilation,']
17 : ['civilizations,[6]']
16 : ['civilization.[7]']
0 : ['']
14 : ['administrative']
18 : ['scholar-officials.']
```

Below is full version of code.

```
text = open("bigdata.txt")
d = dict()

for line in text:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.lower()
    words = line.split(" ")

    for word in words:
        if len(word) in d:
            if word not in d[len(word)]:
                d[len(word)].append(word)
        else:
            d[len(word)] = [word]

for key in list(d.keys()):
    print(key, ":", d[key])
```

Comment: this is what i got in output    0 : ['']

Comment: I added the output I receive. Can you share your text file, then I can try for it too. @IsrarAwan

Comment: Yes this is working but it started from 5 length words but it should start from 0 ike we run the loop it will itrate each word and will find the lenght and then it will save in it's similar length list

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of word lengths and then process them through python's built-in Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

with open("mytext.txt", "r") as f:
    words = f.read().split()
    words_lengths = [len(word) for word in words]
    counter = Counter(words_lengths)
```

The output would be smth like:

```
In[1]:counter
Out[1]:Counter({7: 146, 9: 73, 5: 73, 4: 146, 1: 73})
```

Where keys are words lengths, and values are the number of times they occurred.

You can work with that as with usual dictionary.